# Cannot assign a value of type '[UIImage?]' to a value of type '[AnyObject]?'

Tags: swift

This is my code please help, I'm following a tutorial but i can't figure out whats wrong. please help.

I'm trying to create a slideshow in swift

```
    var logoImages: [UIImage] = []
    logoImages.append(UIImage(named: "logo.png")!)

    imageView.animationImages = [
        UIImage(named: "jade2.jpg"),
        UIImage(named: "jade1.jpg"),
        UIImage(named: "jade14.png")
    ]

     imageView.animationDuration = 5
     imageView.startAnimating()
```

I would be thankful for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are optional in your `animationImages` so add `!` after every images and it will work fine.

And your code will be:

```
imageView.animationImages = [UIImage(named: "jade2.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "jade1.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "jade14.png")!
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to unwrap your optional images by using an exclamation mark: !

Secondly I would suggest creating the image array first, purely for debugging reasons. Having too much going on in a block of code like that can be difficult to debug.

```
var animationImages = [UIImage(named: "jade2.jpg")!,
    UIImage(named: "jade1.jpg")!,
    UIImage(named: "jade14.png")!
    ]
imageView.animationImages = animationImages

imageView.animationDuration = 5
imageView.startAnimating()
```